# Crical Call Io Exception:Critical tunnel Failure problem in black berry

Tags: blackberry

In my app i connecting with web,it not showing any error but when i installed app in phone it shows critical call io exception:critical tunnel failure. why this error occurs.Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the link can solve your problem:http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_make_an_HTTP_or_socket_connection.html?nodeid=826935&vernum=0

And also you can use the following sample code:

private static String getConnectionString(){
    String connectionString="";
    if(WLANInfo.getWLANState()==WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED){
        connectionString=";interface=wifi";
    }

```
 else if((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS){
     connectionString = ";deviceside=false";
}
    else if((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT)==CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT){
        String carrierUid=getCarrierBIBSUid();
        if(carrierUid == null) {
            connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
        }
        else{
             connectionString = ";deviceside=false;connectionUID="+carrierUid + ";ConnectionType=mds-public";
            }               
        }
 else if(CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_NONE)
    {

    }
return connectionString;
}
```